# Ubuntu drive with windows programs

Tags: usb

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but I'm not seeing this anywhere.

I have Ubuntu 16 installed on a 32 3.0 USB drive. I want to install some utility programs on the drive for windows. Not to run windows programs with wine, but plug the USB into a windows machine and use it like thumb drive with utilities on it . . . and also be able to boot Ubuntu off of it when needed. I hope that makes sense, I can't imagine this not being asked before, but every time I try to describe the question in a search engine I come up with answers on how to run windows programs from within Ubuntu using wine.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it gets a bit more complicated then that.

You would need to find portable versions of your "utilities", because you can't just move program installs from one machine to another.

Assuming you were able to find portable versions, the next thing you need to do is partition the drive.

So boot up Ubuntu, and fire up the terminal. Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Open up the newly installed gparted and shrink your main Linux EXT4 volume by however much you want. So if you want 8GB available for Windows utilities, you need to shrink it by 8GB.

After that, you need to format that empty space you just created as NTFS.

Then you're good to go!